# rle-like function that catches "run" of adjacent integers

Tags: r

I'm pretty sure that you all agree that `rle` is one of those "gotcha" functions in R. Is there any similar function that can "catch" a "run" of adjacent integer values?

So, if I have a vector like this one:

```
x <- c(3:5, 10:15, 17, 22, 23, 35:40)
```

and I call that esoteric function, I'll get response like this one:

```
lengths: 3, 6, 1, 2, 6
values: (3,4,5), (10,11,12... # you get the point
```

It's not that hard to write a function like this, but still... any ideas?

Comment: I believe you meant lengths 3, 6, 1, 2, 6... also, what would you do with C(4,4,5,6,9)?

Comment: I reckon the code golfers might have a day with this one!

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect intervals of the consequent integer sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400901/detect-intervals-of-the-consequent-integer-sequences)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1) Calculate values and then lengths based on values**

```
s <- split(x, cumsum(c(0, diff(x) != 1)))
run.info <- list(lengths = unname(sapply(s, length)), values = unname(s))
```

Running it using `x` from the question gives this:

```
> str(run.info)
List of 2
 $ lengths: int [1:5] 3 6 1 2 6
 $ values :List of 5
  ..$ : num [1:3] 3 4 5
  ..$ : num [1:6] 10 11 12 13 14 15
  ..$ : num 17
  ..$ : num [1:2] 22 23
  ..$ : num [1:6] 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

**2)  Calculate lengths and then values based on lengths**

Here is a second solution based on [Gregor's length calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466807/rle-like-function-that-catches-run-of-adjacent-integers/8467765#8467765):

```
lens <- rle(x - seq_along(x))$lengths 
list(lengths = lens, values = unname(split(x, rep(seq_along(lens), lens))))
```

**3)  Calculate lengths and values without using other**

This one seems inefficient since it calculates each of `lengths` and `values` from scratch and it also seems somewhat overly complex but it does manage to get it all down to a single statement so I thought I would add it as well.  Its basically just a mix of the prior two solutions marked 1) and 2) above.  Nothing really new relative to those two.

```
list(lengths = rle(x - seq_along(x))$lengths,
           values = unname(split(x, cumsum(c(0, diff(x) != 1)))))
```

**EDIT:** Added second solution.

**EDIT:** Added third solution.

Comment: Very nice.  And if you're willing to use `rle`, this can be simplified to `rle(cumsum(c(0, diff(x) != 1)))$length`

Comment: @Josh, That only calculates the lengths and seems not really simpler.

Comment: OK -- I should have read the question more carefully, and it makes your solution all the more impressive.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
rle(x - 1:length(x))$lengths   
# 3 6 1 2 6
```

The lengths are what you want, though I'm blanking on an equally clever way to get the proper values, but with `cumsum()` and the original `x` they're very accessible.

Answer (score 5):

As you say, it is easy enough to write something similar to `rle`.  Indeed, adjusting the code for `rle` by adding `+ 1` might give something like

```
rle_consec <- function(x)
{
    if (!is.vector(x) && !is.list(x))
        stop("'x' must be an atomic vector")
    n <- length(x)
    if (n == 0L)
    return(structure(list(lengths = integer(), values = x),
             class = "rle_consec"))
    y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] + 1
    i <- c(which(y | is.na(y)), n)
    structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]),
              class = "rle_consec")
}
```

and using your example

```
> x <- c(3:5, 10:15, 17, 22, 23, 35:40)
> rle_consec(x)
$lengths
[1] 3 6 1 2 6

$values
[1]  5 15 17 23 40

attr(,"class")
[1] "rle_consec"
```

which is what John expected.

You could adjust the code further to give the first of each consecutive subsequence rather than the last.

Answer (score 2):

I recently posted my  `seqle` code here, based on code posted here before even that :-) .

You can find it at [detect intervals of the consequent integer sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400901/detect-intervals-of-the-consequent-integer-sequences)