# Find longest consecutive number in R

Tags: r

Hi I have a list of number like this c(1,2,10,41,42,43,50). The length of longest consecutive streak would be 3 and it starts at 41. However how can I implement it in R? Many thanks!

Comment: start with something like `rle(diff(x)==1)`

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but a subset of the question on [an RLE-like function for consecutive integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8466807/903061).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one possible solution

```
v <- c(1,2,10,41,42,43,50) # Your data
temp <- cumsum(c(1, diff(v) - 1))
temp2 <- rle(temp)
v[which(temp == with(temp2, values[which.max(lengths)]))]
# [1] 41 42 43
```

Answer (score 6):

One way is to split the vector into its sequences then take the longest element of the list.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 10, 41, 42, 43, 50)
s <- split(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 1)))
s[[which.max(lengths(s))]]
# [1] 41 42 43
```

Note that in the case of a tie, the first longest set would be returned.

Comment: I deleted my answer in favor of this one. This link *might* be useful as an addition though: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-December/149006.html