# Get monthly longest consecutive number in r, sum it and store it

Tags: r, function, matrix, storage

My first question here at Stackoverflow :) I hope that you will be able to help me out.

I have tried to find the longest consecutive amount of rainy days a month in a dataset, sum the total of rain and then store both the amount of days that rain lasted and the sum of rain in a matrix. I succeeded in acquiring the amount of days rain and store it, however it took 2,5 hours to run for one scenario and 283 points (12 models x 4 scenarios more to follow:). I read somewhere that reading and writing to a matrix is inefficient, so my guess is that the operation could be more efficient.

This link already helps on the way [longest consecutive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639110/find-longest-consecutive-number-in-r), however my question goes further.

For this question it is better to use 2 years of daily rain values, that i link with dates to find the longest consecutive rainy days amount for each month and each year. I write the output to a matrix. And then performed for 10 points in the basin.

The function used to get the consecutive number and write it to the matrix:

```
WriteRainyDaysCountToMatrix <- function(myDataFrame, myDates, mymatrix, i)
{
  monthsAmount <- 24
  for (monthNumber in 1:monthsAmount){
  #print(cat("monthNumber = ", monthNumber))
  year <- toString(myDates[monthNumber,2])
  month <- toString(myDates[monthNumber,1])
  dayCounter <- 0
  precipitationMax <- 0
  lastRowPrecipitation <- F

  for (rowNumber in 1:nrow(myDataFrame)){
    rowDate <- myDataFrame[rowNumber,1]
    rowYear <- substr(rowDate,1,4)
    rowMonth <- substr(rowDate,5,6)

    if (rowYear == year && rowMonth == month){
      rowPrecipitation <- myDataFrame[rowNumber,2]

      if (rowPrecipitation > 0){
        dayCounter <- dayCounter + 1
        lastRowPrecipitation <- T
        }
        else{
          if (lastRowPrecipitation == T && precipitationMax == 0){
          precipitationMax <- dayCounter
          dayCounter <- 0
          lastRowPrecipitation <- F
        }
      else if (lastRowPrecipitation == T && precipitationMax < dayCounter){
        precipitationMax <- dayCounter
        dayCounter <- 0
        lastRowPrecipitation <- F
      }
      else{
        dayCounter <- 0
        lastRowPrecipitation <- F
      }
    }
  }
}
if (lastRowPrecipitation == T && precipitationMax == 0){
  precipitationMax <- dayCounter
 }
 mymatrix[[monthNumber,i]] <- precipitationMax
}
return (mymatrix)
}
```

An empty matrix to store values is defined here:

```
pmatrix_hist <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=12,ncol=10,dimnames=list(c(1:24),c(1:10)))
```

The dates as input (text file) myDates:

01  1981, 02    1981, 03    1981, 04    1981,
05  1981, 06    1981, 07    1981, 08    1981, 09    1981, 10    1981,
11  1981, 12    1981, 01    1982, 02    1982, 03    1982, 04    1982,
05  1982, 06    1982, 07    1982, 08    1982, 09    1982, 10    1982,
11  1982, 12    1982, etc

Time_step_hist comes from a text file containing dates over 2 years in this format:

19810101, 19810102, 19810103, 19810104, 19810105 etc

Then a for loop to do the work for me:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   # loop over dates and acquire date       
   Prec_hist = read.table(paste(P_read_table_hist$V1[i]), header=F)
   # then put date and rain together
   data_Prec_Hist <- data.frame(Time_step_hist[1:7305,],     Prec_hist[1:7305,]) 
   # call function to get and write to matrix
   pmatrix_hist <- WriteRainyDaysCountToMatrix(data_Prec_Hist,  Dates_hist, pmatrix_hist, i)
   }
```

I do not know how to put in the rain data I use, but a simple list of 0's and 1's can be used instead.

In the matrix only the amount of days is stored, a second matrix to store the sum of rain during these consecutive days is a possibility.

Where are the biggest performance gains possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!
You are correct in your instinct that this kind of operation should be measured in seconds, not hours.

Your biggest gains are going to come from minimizing loops, and using vectorized functions.

A good place to start is with using as.Date to convert your strings to dates, and using subsetting to simplify your loops.

Instead of all those nested loops to go through the years, and months, consider `as.Date('19810101',"%Y%m%d")` to convert your strings to dates.

Here is what a revised structure might look like, I had to take a guess that your "myDataFrame" had a column of dates, and a column of precipitation values.

```
set.seed(42)#for repeatability
#Dummy Data
#some dates
dates <- seq(as.Date("19810101","%Y%m%d"), as.Date("19821231","%Y%m%d"), by = "day")
#random Precipitation
precip <- sample(0:3,length(dates), replace = TRUE, prob = c(.7,.1,.1,.1))
myDataFrame<- data.frame(dates,precip)

#
#real code
#

#Create a month Column
myDataFrame$month <- as.numeric(format(myDataFrame$dates,'%m'))
myDataFrame$year <- as.numeric(format(myDataFrame$dates,'%Y'))

#order your data frame by date
myDataFrame[order(as.Date(myDataFrame$dates)),]

#create lists of the months, and years to drive loops later
yr_list <- levels(factor(myDataFrame$year))
mo_list <- levels(factor(myDataFrame$month))

#A smoother loop structure will look like like this, relying on subsetting 
for(y in yr_list){
  suby <- subset(myDataFrame, myDataFrame[,"year"] == y)
  for(m in mo_list){
    subm <- subset(suby, suby[,"month"] ==m)
    for(d in 1:length(subm)){
      #here you can run your count for each month, and then write the record
      #to a data structure of your choosing
        } 
      }
    }
```

Some things that would help in the future: 1)dput what your data sources look like 2)show a minimal example of what the output is you are going for.

Some tips general tips: Subsetting the date you introduce into your script can help you iterate faster, and look up system.time() and proc.time() to measure your code to see what improvements you change have made.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for your comment. I will have to change quit a bit I see!