# Detect ranges from string of numbers

Tags: r, vector, range

There is a vector I have which looks like this

```
c(3,4,5,6,7,10,11,14,17,18,19,54,55,56,59,61)->k
```

how can I easily detect ranges of consecutive numbers so that

```
3:7,10,11,14,17:19,54:56,59,61
```

and save that in a new vector? In those cases in which there is a range (:) it would be good to have the median of this range save so the output would be

```
5,10,11,14,18,55,59,61
```

is there any other solution quick and can also handle vectors which are not ascending like this
12,3,4,5,0,7

into 
12,4,0,7

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but very related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8466807/903061

Comment: Why are you using `->`? Is this some type of mutiny? :)

Answer (score 5):

**1)** Try this:

```
tapply(k, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1)), median)
```

giving:

```
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
 5.0 10.5 14.0 18.0 55.0 59.0 61.0
```

**2)** Also try this:

```
f <- function(x) if (length(x) == 1) x else paste(x[1], x[length(x)], sep = ":")
tapply(k, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1)), f)
```

giving:

```
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7 
  "3:7" "10:11"    "14" "17:19" "54:56"    "59"    "61"
```

**3)** and this:

```
tapply(k, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1)), toString)
```

giving this:

```
              1               2               3               4               5 
"3, 4, 5, 6, 7"        "10, 11"            "14"    "17, 18, 19"    "54, 55, 56" 
              6               7 
           "59"            "61"
```

**4)** and this:

```
split(k, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1)))
```

giving:

```
$`1`
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

$`2`
[1] 10 11

$`3`
[1] 14

$`4`
[1] 17 18 19

$`5`
[1] 54 55 56

$`6`
[1] 59

$`7`
[1] 61
```

None of the above require any external packages.

Comment: is there a chance to modify that it rounds automatically in cases in which th emedian is not a normal number (10.5..in the case above)?

Comment: Try `round(tapply(...))`

Comment: my vector is very long over 1 mill values and it is not straightly ascending..it happens that it wocoudl be 12,3,4,5,07...is there a nice solution? which can be processed quickly?

Comment: In that case please fix the question.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `vapply` and `range` (only `base R` functions)

```
 f1 <- function(x) paste(unique(range(x)), collapse=":")
 vapply(split(k, cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(k)!=1))), f1, character(1L)) 
 #   1       2       3       4       5       6       7 
 # "3:7" "10:11"    "14" "17:19" "54:56"    "59"    "61"
```

Or if you need `median`

```
vapply(split(k, cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(k)!=1))), FUN= median, double(1L))
#   1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
# 5.0 10.5 14.0 18.0 55.0 59.0 61.0
```

For big vectors, as @David Arenburg mentioned in the comments, some `data.table` options are

```
 library(data.table)
 as.data.table(k)[, median(k), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1))]
 as.data.table(k)[, paste(unique(range(k)), collapse = ";"), 
               cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1))
```

#### Update

Using the new vector "k1"

```
 k1 <- c(12,3,4,5,0,7)
  vapply(split(k1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k1)!=1))), FUN=median, 
              double(1L))
  # 1  2  3  4 
  #12  4  0  7 
as.data.table(k1)[, median(k1) ,cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k1)!=1))]
#    cumsum V1
# 1:      1 12
# 2:      2  4
# 3:      3  0
# 4:      4  7
```

Comment: Some nice solutions there (the `paste(unique(range(x))` is brilliant. Not sure if worth adding `as.data.table(k)[, median(k), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1))]; as.data.table(k)[, paste(unique(range(k)), collapse = ";"), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1))]` as a possible enhancement for big vectors. Or the `if & else` version `as.data.table(k)[, if(.N > 1L) paste(range(k), collapse = ";")  else paste(k), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1))]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  tried the data table solution and it turns out that it doiesnt work is the number is noit ascending..so look at a input vector like 12,3,4,5,0,7

Comment: @triub Thanks for the comment.  Have you tried the `vapply`?

Comment: @akrun yes but it is at least for a test data of 100k values way slower than data table.....might it be using it inocorrectly?

Comment: @triub Based on the example showed, it is working for data.table.  I updated the post with the result

Comment: @akrun that is funny i get the following error ..if it type class(k) it says integer and then I run the line and get Error in `[.data.table`(as.data.table(k), , median(k), cumsum(c(TRUE,  : 
  Column 1 of result for group 782724 is type 'double' but expecting type 'integer'. Column types must be consistent for each group.

Comment: @triub I started with `k1` as class `numeric`.  You may need to convert to `numeric` or `integer` depending on the value computed i.e. `as.data.table(k1)[, k1:=as.integer(k1)][]`

Comment: @triub I would guess `as.data.table(k)[, k:=as.numeric(k)][, median(k),cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(k) != 1))]` to work, though it is taking some time to run