# R: recursive function to give groups of consecutive numbers

Tags: r, if-statement, recursion, vector, integer

Given a sorted vector `x`:

```
x <- c(1,2,4,6,7,10,11,12,15)
```

I am trying to write a small function that will yield a similar sized vector `y` giving the last consecutive integer in order to group consecutive numbers. In my case it is (defining groups 2, 4, 7, 12 and 15):

```
> y
[1]  2  2  4  7  7 12 12 12 15
```

I tried this this recursive idea (were x is the vector, and i an index that would start by 1 in most cases: if the content of the next index is one larger than the current i, then call the function with i+1; else return the content):

```
fun <- function(x,i){
  ifelse(x[i]+1 == x[i+1],
         fun(x,i+1),
         return(x[i]))
}
```

However:

```
> sapply(x,fun,1)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

How to get this to work.

Comment: Not a dupe, but very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8466807/903061

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sapply call is applying `fun` across all values of `x`, when you really want it to be applying across all values of `i`. To get the sapply to do what I assume you want to do, you can do the following:

```
sapply(X = 1:length(x), FUN = fun, x = x)

[1]  2  2  4  7  7 12 12 12 NA
```

Although it returns NA as the last value instead of 15. This is because I don't think your function is set up to handle the last value of a vector (there is no x[10], so it returns NA). You can probably edit your function to handle this fairly easily.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

```
find_non_consec <- function(x){ c(x[which(as.logical(diff(x)-1))],x[length(x)]) }
x <- c(1,2,4,6,7,10,11,12,15)
res <- find_non_consec(x)
```

The result is:

```
> res
[1]  2  4  7 12 15
```

This function identifies the numbers where the series ceases to be consecutive.