# Find originating time points within groups

Tags: r

For sequences measured at different time points, I am interested the time point in which each sequence originates, resetting the originating time point if there is a skip.

```
dd <- data.frame(seq = letters[c(1:6,1,6:7,1:3,7:8,1)],
                 grp = rep(1:5, c(3,4,5,2,1)))
o2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,1,3,3,3,4,5)

par(mar = c(5, 5, 2, 5), las = 1, bty = 'n', xpd = NA)
plot(as.numeric(dd$seq), dd$grp, col = o2, pch = 16,
     cex = 3, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = 'seq', ylab = '')
axis(1, at = 1:8, letters[1:8], lwd = 0)
axis(2, at = 1:5, paste0('time ', 1:5))
axis(4, at = 1:5, palette()[1:5])
```

Maybe this will better illustrate: For each sequence that occurs consecutively, I want to assign that group to the lowest time point and color it accordingly.

[image]

So the first group of a starts at time 1 and continues uninterrupted until 3, so theoretically this is the same sequence which originated at time 1. Since there is another group of a, this is assumed not to be related to the other group of a and colored for time point 5.

b and c have two origins so they are colored individually according to the time points.

My desired result is this vector, `o2`

```
# split(cbind(dd, desired = o2), dd$grp)
cbind(dd, desired = o2)

#    seq grp desired
# 1    a   1       1
# 2    b   1       1
# 3    c   1       1
# 4    d   2       2
# 5    e   2       2
# 6    f   2       2
# 7    a   2       1
# 8    f   3       2
# 9    g   3       3
# 10   a   3       1
# 11   b   3       3
# 12   c   3       3
# 13   g   4       3
# 14   h   4       4
# 15   a   5       5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possibility using `dplyr`

```
pd <- dd %>% arrange(seq,grp) %>% 
    group_by(seq) %>%
    mutate(set=cumsum(grp-lag(grp, default=100)!=1)) %>%
    group_by(seq,set) %>%
    mutate(colgrp=min(grp))
```

Which you plot with

```
par(mar = c(5, 5, 2, 5), las = 1, bty = 'n', xpd = NA)
plot(as.numeric(pd$seq), pd$grp, col = pd$colgrp, pch = 16,
     cex = 3, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = 'seq', ylab = '')
axis(1, at = 1:8, letters[1:8], lwd = 0)
axis(2, at = 1:5, paste0('time ', 1:5))
axis(4, at = 1:5, palette()[1:5])
```

Note the weird `default=100` value. Ideally i'd like to use `-1` or something outside the range, but thanks to [this bug](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1411) you can't enter negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by my answer to [rle-like function that catches runs of adjacent integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8466807/903061)

```
dd %>% group_by(seq) %>%
    arrange(grp) %>%
    mutate(origin_group = grp - 0:(n() - 1)) %>%
    group_by(seq, origin_group) %>%
    mutate(origin = min(grp))
```

This is very similar to MrFlick's answer, I just use a slightly different method of doing the first grouping.

```
par(mar = c(5, 5, 2, 5), las = 1, bty = 'n', xpd = NA)
plot(as.numeric(dd2$seq), dd2$grp, col = dd2$origin, pch = 16,
     cex = 3, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = 'seq', ylab = '')
axis(1, at = 1:8, letters[1:8], lwd = 0)
axis(2, at = 1:5, paste0('time ', 1:5))
axis(4, at = 1:5, palette()[1:5])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I am currently using

```
## two helper functions
cum_reset <- function(x, value = 0L, FUN = cummin) {
  ## reset a cum* fn if value is encountered
#   x <- 1:10
#   x[x %% 3 == 0] <- 0
#   cum_reset(x)
#   cum_reset(1:10, value = c(4,6))
  idx <- c(0, head(cumsum(x %in% value), -1))
  sp <- split(x, idx)
  unname(unlist(lapply(sp, FUN)))
}

do_reset <- function(x, FUN = min) {
  # a <- dd$grp[dd$seq == 'a']
  # b <- dd$grp[dd$seq == 'b']
  o <- rep(0, max(x))
  o[x] <- x
  o <- cum_reset(o)
  o[o > 0]
}

o3 <- with(dd, ave(grp, seq, FUN = do_reset))
all(o2 == o3) # TRUE
cbind(dd, desired = o2, got = o3)

#    seq grp desired got
# 1    a   1       1   1
# 2    b   1       1   1
# 3    c   1       1   1
# 4    d   2       2   2
# 5    e   2       2   2
# 6    f   2       2   2
# 7    a   2       1   1
# 8    f   3       2   2
# 9    g   3       3   3
# 10   a   3       1   1
# 11   b   3       3   3
# 12   c   3       3   3
# 13   g   4       3   3
# 14   h   4       4   4
# 15   a   5       5   5
```

Test on a larger data set

```
dd2 <- rbind(dd, within(dd, grp <- grp + 5))
(o4 <- with(dd2, ave(grp, seq, FUN = do_reset)))
# [1]  1  1  1  2  2  2  1  2  3  1  3  3  3  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  7  5  7  8  5  8  8  8  9 10

par(mar = c(5, 5, 2, 5), las = 1, bty = 'n', xpd = NA)
plot(as.numeric(dd2$seq), dd2$grp, col = o4, pch = 16, cex = 3,
     xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = 'seq', ylab = '')
axis(1, at = 1:8, letters[1:8], lwd = 0)
axis(2, at = 1:10, paste0('time ', 1:10))
axis(4, at = 1:10, rep_len(palette(), 10))
```

[image]

**option 2**

Using a combination of matt and gregor's answers, here is another solution in base r

EDIT added extra line to account for duplicates in which the others will fail

```
dat <- dd2
(origins <- ave(seq_along(rownames(dat)), dat$seq, FUN = function(x) {
  ## fix for duplicates
  dat$grp[x] <- dat$grp[x] + cumsum(duplicated(dat$grp[x]))
  gr <- dat$grp[x] - 0:(length(dat$seq[x]) - 1)
  ave(dat$grp[x], gr, FUN = min)
}))
# [1]  1  1  1  2  2  2  1  2  3  1  3  3  3  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  7  5  7  8  5  8  8  8  9 10

par(mar = c(5, 5, 2, 5), las = 1, bty = 'n', xpd = NA)
plot(as.numeric(dat$seq), dat$grp, col = origins, pch = 16,
     cex = 3, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = 'seq', ylab = '')
axis(1, at = 1:8, letters[1:8], lwd = 0)
axis(2, at = 1:10, paste0('time ', 1:10))
axis(4, at = 1:10, rep_len(palette(), 10))
```