# package or function to count sequence lengths?

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is a package or generic function in R that counts sequence lengths. 
For instance, if I input a sequence

s1<-c('a','a','b','a','a','a','b','b')

The proposed function F(s1,'a') would return a vector: 
[2,3]
and F(s1,'b') would return [1,2]

Comment: Several people are currently madly typing as fast as they can to tell you about `rle`.

Comment: perfect, I should have remembered that. Thanks.

Comment: Several of us have written `seqle` which can search for either repetitions or sequences.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400901/detect-intervals-of-the-consequent-integer-sequences

Comment: +1. I'm surprised this question wasn't upvoted before. It just saved me from posting a question and/or spending hours of work. I'd never heard about this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those madly typing people must have gone elsewhere:

```
 s1<- c('a','a','b','a','a','a','b','b')
 F1 <- function(s, el) {rle(s)$lengths[rle(s)$values==el] }
 F1(s1, "a")
#[1] 2 3
 F1(s1, "b")
#[1] 1 2
```