# Measure the periodicity of a sequence of numbers [R]

Tags: r, sequence

A periodic sequence is a sequence that repeats itself after *n* terms, for example, the following is a periodic sequence:

1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...

And we define the *period* of that sequence to be the number of terms in each subsequence (the subsequence above is 1, 2, 3).  So the period for the above sequence is 3.

In R, I can define the above sequence (albeit not to infinity), using:

```
sequence <- rep(c(1,2,3),n) #n is a predefined variable
```

So if `n = 50`, `sequence` will be the sequence 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ... , 1, 2, 3, where each number has appeared 50 times, in the obvious way.

I am looking to build a function that calculates the periodicity of `sequence`.  Pseudocode is as follows:

```
period <- function(sequence){
    subsequence <- subsequence(sequence) #identify the subsequence
    len.subsequence <- length(subsequence) #calculate its length
    return(len.subsequence) #return it
}
```

How would I identify the subsequence? This is sort of a reversing of the `rep` function, such that I pass in a sequence and it passes out the length of the initial vector.

Comment: I occurs to me that things can get hairy if there are repeated subsequences, e.g.  `1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5` .  As DWIN and mdrwab pointed out, nonmonotonic sequences may yield "diff = 0" results erroneously.  Maybe you should just take the Fourier transform and look for peaks :-)

Comment: @dplanet, how did any of the answers below work out for you? If they didn't, can you indicate what further you might be looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the period is always the same, i.e. the sequence never changes, then you could use a loop over `lag` to see when a match occurs.

With total bias, I would also recommend using  `seqle` (guess who wrote that function :-) ), which is like `rle` but finds sequences.   [detect intervals of the consequent integer sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400901/detect-intervals-of-the-consequent-integer-sequences) 
I'm not the only person to edit the source for "rle" that way.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy with that sequence, although I would avoid using the name 'sequence' since it is an R function name. This would identify the periodicity of any monotonic sequence so it's a bit more general but it would not identify a sequence like: 1.2.3.4.2.3.4,1,2,3,4,2,3,4, ....

```
> which(diff(seQ) < 0)
[1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
> diff(which(diff(seQ) < 0) )
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

You could test the equality of intervals or use either of those results to index the original vector. You should test your answers with c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4) to see if they pass the test of identifying an non-monotonic repetition. So far none of them do so; since none report a period of 7.

Comment: I've [taken a stab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12826587/1270695) at trying to identify non-monotonic repetition, but I'm not really comfortable (no prior experience) with using `while()`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Building on the lead from @DWin, you can probably make a function something like this:

```
subsequence <- function(data) {
  ii <- 0
  while (TRUE) {
    ii <- ii + 1
    LAG <- sum((diff(data, lag = ii) == 0) - 1)
    if (LAG == 0) { break }
  }
  list(Period = ii, 
       Sequence = data[1:ii], 
       Reps = length(data)/ii) 
}
```

**Note**: *This was my first time using `while()`, so I'm not sure if there's a better way to implement it.*

Here is some data; s3 is non-monotonic:

```
s1 <- rep(c(1,2,3), 3)
s2 <- rep(c(1,2,3), 50)
s3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4)
```

Here are the results of the `subsequence()` function.

```
subsequence(s1)
# $Period
# [1] 3
# 
# $Sequence
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $Reps
# [1] 3

subsequence(s2)
# $Period
# [1] 3
# 
# $Sequence
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $Reps
# [1] 50

subsequence(s3)
# $Period
# [1] 7
# 
# $Sequence
# [1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4
# 
# $Reps
# [1] 2
```