# How to count a repeating repeating part of a sequence in R?

Tags: r, count, sequence, repeat

Is it possible to count a repeating part of a sequence in R? 
For example:

```
x<- c(1,3.0,3.1,3.2,1,1,2,3.0,3.1,3.2,4,4,5,6,5,3.0,3.1,3.2,
      3.1,2,1,4,6,4.0,4,3.0,3.1,3.2,5,3.2,3.0,4)
```

Is it possible to count the times that the subsequence 3.0,3.1,3.2 occurs? So in this example it must be: 4

Comment: Do you just want to count that particular subsequence? Or do you want to identify any other subsequences that might be in your data?

Comment: Insert standard warning about matching floating-point values. Unless you need to keep everything numeric, you may want to run your data through `sprintf("%2f",mydata)` or equivalent so you can do exact matches on strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
pattern <- c(3, 3.1, 3.2)
len1 <- seq_len(length(x) - length(pattern) + 1)
len2 <- seq_len(length(pattern))-1
sum(colSums(matrix(x[outer(len1, len2, '+')], 
     ncol=length(len1), byrow=TRUE) == pattern) == length(len2))
```

PS: by changing `sum` to `which` you'll get the start of each instance.

Answer (score 3):

One more (generic moving window) approach:

```
x <- c(1,3.0,3.1,3.2,1,1,2,3.0,3.1,3.2,4,4,5,6,5,3.0,3.1,3.2, 3.1,2,1,4,6,4.0,4,3.0,3.1,3.2,5,3.2,3.0,4)
s <- c(3, 3.1, 3.2)

sum(apply(embed(x, length(s)), 1, function(y) {all(y == rev(s))}))
# [1] 4
```

See output of `embed` to understand what's happening.

As Arun points out `apply` here is pretty slow, and one can use `embed` together with Arun's `matrix` trick to get this to be a lot faster:

```
sum(colSums(matrix(embed(x, length(s)),
                   byrow = TRUE, nrow = length(s)) == rev(s)) == length(s))
```

Comment: I ran across `embed` at first as well. But a vector scan required taking transpose. Or one should be using `apply`. I reverted therefore to constructing the matrix row-wise.

Comment: makes sense, I just tested and this is slightly faster than your `outer` approach when one gets rid of `apply` and does your `matrix` thing; I'll edit that approach in as well

Answer (score 2):

You could turn it into a string, and use `gregexpr`.

```
sum(gregexpr("3 3.1 3.2", paste(x, collapse=" "), fixed=TRUE)[[1]] != -1)
[1]  4
```

Comment: This'll give an answer of 1 when there's no match, because `gregexpr` returns -1 in case of no match.

Comment: this gives incorrect results for overlapping sequences: `x = c(1,2,2,2,3,2,2); s = c(2,2)`

Comment: @eddi It's a bit silly to say it's "incorrect" when you actually have no idea what the OP wants to do with overlapping sequences, or in fact, if overlapping sequences need to be considered at all.

Comment: @HongOoi I think you should attempt to fix instead of getting defensive, the fact that this does smth else for overlapping sequences than the other solutions should at least give you a pause

Comment: @eddi Fixing something assumes there is something to fix. As I said, you don't actually know what is the desired output when sequences can overlap, or even if sequences can overlap. You have _assumed_ that they can occur, and you have _assumed_ that a particular output in that case is the correct one. Neither of these assumptions can be proved true until/unless the OP clarifies.

Comment: @HongOoi *shrug* extending that logic `print(4)` is also a solution to OP; just because it's an input *you* haven't anticipated, doesn't mean your response when someone points it out should be "that particular input is not in the OP"; anyway, if you don't want to fix it - that's fine obviously, hopefully my comment will be useful for whomever reads this answer in the future

Comment: @eddi Indeed, "4" is an answer to the question "count the times that the subsequence 3.0,3.1,3.2 occurs", in the specific sequence given. Because we are humans and not computers, however, we can understand from context that the specific numbers given are to be treated as placeholders for more general expressions. However, the specification of the problem as stated remains ambiguous for certain edge cases. I simply say that calling particular interpretations "incorrect" in the existence of ambiguity is... silly.

Comment: If we wanted to be utterly pedantic, in fact, the REAL answer is `TRUE`: it _is_ "possible to count the times...". I guess we've all been barking up the wrong tree....

Comment: @HongOoi FWIW If you want to catch overlapping patterns, you could wrap the pattern in a lookahead assertion, and set `fixed=FALSE, perl=TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

Carl Witthoft's [`seqle` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8402950/1270695) might be useful for you here.

The function looks like this:

```
seqle <- function(x,incr=1) { 
    if(!is.numeric(x)) x <- as.numeric(x) 
    n <- length(x)  
    y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] + incr 
    i <- c(which(y|is.na(y)),n) 
    list(lengths = diff(c(0L,i)),
         values = x[head(c(0L,i)+1L,-1L)]) 
}
```

Applied to your data, it should look like this:

```
temp <- seqle(x, incr=.1)
temp
# $lengths
#  [1] 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1
# 
# $values
#  [1] 1.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 5.0 3.0 3.1 2.0 1.0 4.0
# [17] 6.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 5.0 3.2 3.0 4.0
```

Now, how do we read that? `lengths` tells us that our vector had a sequence of 1, then of 3, then of 1, and of 1, and of 1, and of 3.... `values` tells us that the first value of the sequence of length 3 was "3.0", the first value of the next sequence of length 3 was "3.0", and so on.

This is easier to see as a `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(temp)[temp$lengths > 1, ]
#    lengths values
# 2        3      3
# 6        3      3
# 12       3      3
# 20       3      3
```

In this example, the lengths of all the sequences are the same, and they start at the same value, so we can get your answer just by looking at the number of rows in the resulting `data.frame` above.

Comment: +1, even though I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants. For ex: the pattern could also be: `c(10, 8, 15)`.

Comment: @Arun, true. Just throwing it out there!

Comment: I have to recuse myself from giving it a +1 for obvious reasons :-). But I am flattered that you'd reference my derivative work.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, you're being modest :). The function is plenty useful! Go ahead, give it a +1 :).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I've done so more than once here on SO! When are you going to package this thing up?

Comment: Well to be honest I've been thinking of making a "my toys" package with `seqle` and `approxeq`  (returns a vector of T/F rather than the `all.equal` output) and `short` (like a customizable combo of 'head' and 'tail').  Keep encouraging me, or send me Butterfingers bars, and I'll try to get it done :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto At long last, I've got the package submitted to CRAN.  It's called `cgwtools` ; currently awaiting CRAN approval.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Awesome. I'll look out for it!