# Split a numeric vector into continuous chunks in R

Tags: r, vector

If I have a numeric vector [1 2 3 4 7 8 9 10 15 16 17], how can I split it so that I have multiple vectors returned that separate the continuous elements of that vector? I.e. [1 2 3 4] [7 8 9 10] [15 16 17]. I've found an answer of how to do this in matlab, but I only use R.

Thanks.

Comment: Some alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400901/detect-intervals-of-the-consequent-integer-sequences

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another alternative:

```
vec <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17 )
split(vec, cumsum(seq_along(vec) %in% (which(diff(vec)>1)+1)))
# $`0`
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# $`1`
# [1]  7  8  9 10
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 15 16 17
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect from what the OP has shown. But seeing that the OP has accepted this answer, you seem to have read his mind! ;)

Comment: @Arun, excellent point, don't know how I stuffed that up... corrected now!

Comment: Apologies - I was a little trigger happy here. I thought that this was the correct solution, but as arun points out, it's not quite what I was asking. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user2728808 Fair enough - sorted out now

Comment: Ok, the OP wants the vector to be split into continuous runs, so this is (the only) correct answer. +1

Comment: @Arun, I think in your example the OP would like to end up with a list of six vectors of length 1

Comment: @alexwhan, dint read the "continuous elements of the vector" part good enough. +1, nice answer!

Comment: Thanks @alexwhan, this is now perfect. Thanks to all for contributing. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
split(vec, cummax(c(1,diff(vec))))
```

Result

```
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`3`
[1]  7  8  9 10

$`5`
[1] 15 16 17
```