# R: Efficient extraction of events (continuous increase in a variable)

Tags: r, events, sequence

The task is to efficiently extract events from this data:

```
data <- structure(
            list(i = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), t = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4), x = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)),
            .Names = c("i", "t", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"
        )

> data
  i t x
1 1 1 1
2 1 2 1
3 1 3 2
4 2 1 1
5 2 3 2
6 2 4 3
```

Let's call `i` facts, `t` is time, and `x` is the number of selections of `i` at `t`.

An event is an uninterrupted sequence of selections of one fact. Fact 1 is selected all throughout t=1 to t=3 with a sum of 4 selections. But fact 2 is split into two events, the first from t=1 to t=1 (sum=1) and the second from t=3 to t=4 (sum=5). Therefore, the event data frame is supposed to look like this:

```
> event
  i from to sum
1 1    1  3   4
2 2    1  1   1
3 2    3  4   5
```

This code does what is needed:

```
event <- structure(
             list(i = logical(0), from = logical(0), to = logical(0), sum = logical(0)),
             .Names = c("i", "from", "to", "sum"), row.names = integer(0),
             class = "data.frame"
         )
l <- nrow(data) # get rows of data frame
c <- 1 # set counter
d <- 1 # set initial row of data to start with
e <- 1 # set initial row of event to fill
repeat{
    event[e,1] <- data[d,1] # store "i" in event data frame
    event[e,2] <- data[d,2] # store "from" in event data frame
    while((data[d+1,1] == data[d,1]) & (data[d+1,2] == data[d,2]+1)){
        c <- c+1
        d <- d+1
        if(d >= l) break
    }
    event[e,3] <- data[d,2] # store "to" in event data frame
    event[e,4] <- sum(data[(d-c+1):d,3]) # store "sum" in event data frame
    c <- 1
    d <- d+1
    e <- e+1
}
```

The problem is that this code takes 3 days to extract the events from a data frame with 1 million rows and my data frame has 5 million rows.

How can I make this more efficient?

P.S.: There's also a minor bug in my code related to termination.

P.P.S.: The data is sorted first by i, then by t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try if this dplyr implementation is faster?

```
library(dplyr)

data <- structure(
    list(fact = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), timing = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4), x = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)),
    .Names = c("fact", "timing", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"
)

group_by(data, fact) %>%
    mutate(fromto=cumsum(c(0, diff(timing) > 1))) %>%
    group_by(fact, fromto) %>%
    summarize(from=min(timing), to=max(timing), sumx=sum(x)) %>%
    select(-fromto) %>%
    ungroup()
```

how about this data.table implementation?

```
library(data.table)
data <- structure(
    list(fact = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), timing = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4), x = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)),
    .Names = c("fact", "timing", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"
)
setDT(data)[, fromto:=cumsum(c(0, diff(timing) > 1)), by=fact]
event <- data[, .(from=min(timing), to=max(timing), sumx=sum(x)), by=c("fact", "fromto")][,fromto:=NULL]

##results when i enter event in the R console and my data.table package version is data.table_1.9.6
> event
   fact from to sumx
1:    1    1  3    4
2:    2    1  1    1
3:    2    3  4    5
> str(event)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ fact: num  1 2 2
 $ from: num  1 1 3
 $ to  : num  3 1 4
 $ sumx: num  4 1 5
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> dput(event)
structure(list(fact = c(1, 2, 2), from = c(1, 1, 3), to = c(3, 
1, 4), sumx = c(4, 1, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("fact", "from", "to", "sumx"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)
```

Reference
[detect intervals of the consequent integer sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400901/detect-intervals-of-the-consequent-integer-sequences)

Comment: Your first implementation took 150 seconds instead of 15 days for my 5 million lines :) Thanks indeed. Your second implementation I couldn't get to work. I ran the first line and then "event <- data[...". Is the code allright? Cause I like the data.table package.

Comment: Thanks. Just run the code as it is. Don't introduce any more event data.table

Comment: Can you please check your data.table implementation? When I run it, it's like the last line doesn't have any effect. But earlier, your fromto column doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: After you run the data.table implementation, just print out data

Comment: That's what I do. data is now the original table with one more column. It's not transformed into the event table. Maybe a version issue? I have checked 3.2.3 and 3.2.4. revised.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data frame is sorted according to `data$t`, you can try something like this

```
event <- NULL
for (i in unique(data$i)) {
    x <- data[data$i == i, ]
    ev <- cumsum(c(1, diff(x$t)) > 1)
    smry <- lapply(split(x, ev), function(z) c(i, range(z$t), sum(z$x)))
    event <- c(event, smry)
}
event <- do.call(rbind, event)
rownames(event) <- NULL
colnames(event) <- c('i', 'from', 'to', 'sum')
```

The result is a matrix, not a data frame.

Comment: Thx for your help. Unfortunately, your algorithm is ten times slower than mine.

Comment: Too bad... You may want to use some profiling tool such as `Rprof` in order to figure out where in your algorithm the bottleneck is.