# counting number of true/talse periods in r

Tags: r, vector, boolean, counter

I have a boolean vector derived from a time series. It basically looks like this: c(true, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, true...).

I want to count the periods in which the vector is true. Example: for a vector like this: c(true, true, false, true) it would be 2 (1 long true period in the beginning, 1 short in the end).

the vector can contain NAs in the beginning.

I thought of something like:

```
aaa <- c(NA,F,T,T,T,F)    
for(j in 1:(length(aaa)-1)){  
  if(aaa[j]!=aaa[j+1]){  
    # add a counter that returns [1]  
  }  
}
```

=================================================

edit: This works fine for me:

```
data.frame("#"=unlist(rle(aaa)[1]),"length"=unlist(rle(aaa)[2]))
```

Comment: What would you expect c(TRUE, NA, TRUE) to give you? The answer to your query's likely to use run length encoding see `?rle`

Comment: Please edit the post to include you comment and also include dummy code to highlight 1) input vector 2) output vector 3) what have you tried so far. Please do look at [how to post a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Miff: c(TRUE, NA, TRUE) should return 2

Comment: `rle(aaa[!is.na(aaa)])` maybe

Comment: similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400901/detect-intervals-of-the-consequent-integer-sequences) if you first convert to index with `which()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
aaa[is.na(aaa)] <- FALSE
sum(rle(aaa)$values)
```

Convert `NA`s to `FALSE`, and the see how many `TRUE` values there are in the run length encoding (`TRUE` is stored as 1, `FALSE` as zero).